# How to prevent cloud run app from attacks or bad traffic

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, networking, google-cloud-run

My app is public and is getting hundreds of requests for pages that do not exist.

My app is not built in wordpress, but the requests keep coming for **.env**, **wp-admin** and others.

[image]

So, my question is:

> Is there a way to block this kind of abusive requests?

Comment: See if this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76458225/can-i-avoid-google-app-engine-instances-from-being-undesirably-created/76469937#76469937) response helps. It's for GAE but it applies to Cloud Run.

Comment: I think @NoCommandLine as the correct pointer: use Load Balancer with Cloud Armor to filter bad traffic (or anything else like Cloud Flare). If you can turn your service in private mode (require authentication) IAP could help you (but I guess you want to let it public)

Comment: What you are seeing is very common. Most public HTTP endpoints receive this type of garbage traffic. Remember an attack is different from a script kiddie probing your server. For the first case, the Google Front End (GFE) will handle most DoS (Denial of Service). For the second case, I just ignore the problem because the cost to return a 404 is minor and a real solution (load balancer + Cloud Armor) is more expensive than the problem. There are thousands of sites scanning other sites which can consume lots of your time trying to block them.

Answer (score 1):

Posting Mr. @JohnHanley, Mr @GuillaumeBlaquiere and @NoCommandLine comments as answer.

I agree with them, since Cloud Run is a serverless service, the firewall will not help you to block these traffics since its not yet supported and the option that we can do is by associating your Cloud Run to [Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless) and configure [Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/cloud-armor-overview) for security purposes.